# Binding options and optionsText in Select dropdown in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I read everything here and different websites and don't understand my problem. Looks like it should work, but it doesn't. I am getting [Object object] as options.

**Html**

```
 <select data-bind="options: Cities, optionsText: Cities.CityNameRu"></select>
```

**Knockout**

```
function CityModel(data) {
    this.CityId = ko.observable(data.CityId);
    this.CityNameRu = ko.observable(data.CityNameRu);
    this.CityName = ko.observable(data.CityName);
}

function IndexModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.Cities = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.GetCities = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/FetchCities',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                self.SuccessfullyRetrievedModelsFromAjax(data);   
            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err.status + " : " + err.statusText);
            }
        });
    };

    this.SuccessfullyRetrievedModelsFromAjax = function (models) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(models, function (model) {
            self.Cities.push(new CityModel(model));
        });
    };
    self.GetCities();
}
```

**Json Response**

```
[{"CityId":1,"CityName":"philadelphia","CityNameRu":"Филадельфия"},{"CityId":2,"CityName":"new-york","CityNameRu":"Нью Йорк"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `optionsText` is the string name of the property within each `options` array element to use for the text, so you should change your binding to:

```
<select data-bind="options: Cities, optionsText: 'CityNameRu'"></select>
```